# Porting app from react-azure-adb2c to react-adal

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I am using Azure AD B2C.
I need some react library to authenticate users in my react.js app.

I started with react-azure-adb2c. Primary scenarios like login and logout worked well for me. However, the library owner stopped supporting the library, so I need to find other one.

Experimenting with [react-adal](https://github.com/salvoravida/react-adal). 
I followed the steps, but got missing '.\store' and 'react-redux'. I installed redux with npm and created some store.
When auth is required, redirect to the sign-in page works, however this is sign in to microsoft account, not to my AD B2C account.

It seems something wrong in configuration:

```
export const adalConfig: AdalConfig = {
    tenant: 'x5aaas.onmicrosoft.com',
    clientId: 'a1568977-3095-4bf6-a6d6-c10c87658488',
    endpoints: {
        api: 'https://x5aaas.onmicrosoft.com/ui/use',
    },
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
};
```

I use basic react app with type script, created with

```
npx create-react-app <appName> --typescript
```

What can be missing?

Comment: I see you have opened another similar issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55645155/porting-app-from-react-azure-adb2c-to-react-aad.  Are you still having issues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the authority should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/<your-tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<your-sign-in-sign-up-policy>`