# How do I make 'forgot password' working in react-aad-msal with Azure AD B2C?

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I am using [react-aad-msal](https://github.com/syncweek-react-aad/react-aad) with Azure AD B2C. I have sign-in and sign-out working. However, when I click 'Forgot your password?', the auth window disappears and nothing happens.

[image]

It seems I need to specify name of my 'forgot password' policy, but I do not know where to put it.

Based on Tony's answer added this code to my App's render:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("error_description=AADB2C90118") >= 0)
    {
      return <AzureAD
      provider={
        new MsalAuthProviderFactory({
          authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/x5aaas.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_PwdReset', 
          clientID: 'a1568977-3095-4bf6-a6d6-c10c87658488',
          scopes: ['https://x5aaas.onmicrosoft.com/ui/use'],
          type: LoginType.Redirect,
          postLogoutRedirectUri: window.origin,
        })
      }
      unauthenticatedFunction={this.unauthenticatedFunction}
      userInfoCallback={this.userJustLoggedIn}
      authenticatedFunction={this.authenticatedFunction}
    />;
    }
```

I see that after I click "Forgot password?", the condition is true, and return happens. However, the window for password reset does not show up and I get redirected back to my app URL.

Any suggestions?

Comment: updated question

Comment: Doesn't seem like the library has a place to configure it. What I've done in the past with a back-end app is configure the forgot password policy as another identity provider in the app. So effectively login using the forgot password policy.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be better to update the library? Do you happen to know some documentation on how it works?

Comment: I don't think updating by itself will help as the library is generic and not made specifically for B2C.

Comment: @TonyJu, I updated my question, based on your answer

Comment: @PolinaC Sorry for the delay. I am not familiar with reactjs. Hope someone else can continue to answer this. If you have figured it out yourself, you can share your solution here to help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was create a Route in my App.js:

```
          <Route
            path="/forgot"
            component={() => {
              window.location.href = forgotPasswordUrl;
              return null;
            }}
          />
```

Then, in the `constructor`

```
if (window.location.hash.indexOf('AADB2C90118') >= 0) {
  history.push('/forgot');
}
```

And that works.

Comment: What is the forgotPasswordUrl?

Comment: @milorad an url from the project where it should be redirected to. Can't recall honestly.

Comment: I used loginRedirect() from the microsoft library and specifying the forgot password relying party as the authority. All other MSAL client application configuration has remained the same as for the sign up sign in policy

Answer (score 2):

When using a combined sign-up/sign-in policy in Azure B2C, users have to handle the forgot password scenario themselves. You can find more detailed comments [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp/issues/9).

A sign-up or sign-in user flow with local accounts includes a "Forgot password?" link on the first page of the experience. Clicking this link doesn't automatically trigger a password reset user flow.

Instead, the error code AADB2C90118 is returned to your application. Your application needs to handle this error code by running a specific user flow that resets the password. To see an example, take a look at a [simple ASP.NET sample](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet-SUSI/tree/complete/WebApp-B2C-DotNet) that demonstrates the linking of user flows.

Answer (score 1):

Using `msal-react` and `msal-browser` I was able to get the Azure AD B2C password reset page to appear using the following code (assuming you created a password reset user flow named `B2C_1_RESET`):

```
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { EventType } from '@azure/msal-browser';

....

const { instance, inProgress, accounts } = useMsal();

// MSAL Logging
//instance.setLogger(new Logger(loggerCallback));

const callbackId = instance.addEventCallback((message) => {
    if (message.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_FAILURE){
      if (message.error.errorMessage.includes("AADB2C90118")) { // The user has forgotten their password.
        const authority = "https://<your_domain>.b2clogin.com/crowdalert.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_RESET";
        instance.loginRedirect({authority: authority})
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Credit to Ian for the hint.

You should add an extra condition in case the user cancels their attempt to change reset their account credentials. This way they are redirected back to login instead of getting stuck on your app.

```
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";

export default MyComponent = () => {

// other code

const { instance, accounts, inProgress } = useMsal();

instance.addEventCallback((message: any) => {
    if (message.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_FAILURE && message.error.errorMessage.includes("AADB2C90118")) {
      // The user has forgotten their password.
      instance.loginRedirect(passwordResetRequest);
    } else if (message.eventType === EventType.HANDLE_REDIRECT_END && inProgress === InteractionStatus.None) {
      instance.loginRedirect(loginRequest);
    }
  });

// rest of component

};
```