# link user flows in react js application

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am using own custom HTML page for my user flows in azure adb2c. I am using react js adb2c libraries in my application. In signup and sign in v2 user flow, there is an option for forgot the password, but the link doesn't take me to my password reset user flow. Error in console: access_denied:AADB2C90118: The user has forgotten their password. I am not getting any samples in react js to solve this issue. This error is thrown from the react-azure-adb2c library. Any suggestion will be great.

Comment: You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55718030/how-do-i-make-forgot-password-working-in-react-aad-msal-with-azure-ad-b2c

Comment: the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55718030/how-do-i-make-forgot-password-working-in-react-aad-msal-with-azure-ad-b2c gives sample in asp.net, but am using react js. is there anyway to link userflows in react js applications?

Comment: We need to to handle the forgot password scenario ourselves. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp/issues/9

Comment: By the way, can you provide the adb2c lib link which you are using?

Comment: i referred this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-azure-adb2c and installed library with command: npm install react-azure-adb2c --save. Am just following the steps as is in that link.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by using this library: https://github.com/leszekczajka/msal-b2c-react
It has option to specify my resetPolicy as well, so when i click on Forgot Password link, am redirected to my reset user flow  which i created in adb2c. Thanks all for your help.